Logs are stopping in the middle and giving empty result in AWS console, but working fine in local terminal
{
    "level": 30,
    "pid": 8,
    "hostname": "***.***.**.**",
    "requestId": "xyz",
    "data": {
        "results": [],
        "statistics": {
            "recordsMatched": 0,
            "recordsScanned": 0,
            "bytesScanned": 0
        },
        "status": "Complete"
    },
    "msg": "inside cloudwatchlogs getQueryResults "
}

In cloudwatch logs it is stopping at this point, due to data result as empty the code is not executing further. In local everything is working fine only on aws it is stopping in the middle due to empty result.
If anyone can help and sorry for my bad English.
